# Where is defined a custom register_taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, urls

Where is defined a custom register_taxonomy for my website url?

Now is showing:

```
http://localhost:1337/wordpress/portfolio-list/yapbond/
```

But I want

```
http://localhost:1337/wordpress/product-list/yapbond/
```

In which file I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use any plugin for this url ? Or Made page or post or category for this URL ?
What to do ? How you generate this url ?

If you are using any plugin, you can see plugin functions.php file.

Comment: No, I am not using plugin for that

Comment: What is portfolio-list ? Its page or category ?

Comment: It is a category

Comment: Okay. And Have you want to change portfolio-list to product-list right ? 
For this you can change category slug. Its automatically change URL.

Comment: yes , I want product-list instead of portfolio-list

Comment: Go to category and edit portfolio-list category and change slug. You don't need to any change in coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really using a wordpress.com blog, I think the fastest way is to create a category called "product-list" and a post called "yapbond".

This probably won't solve your problem, but, If you are using a wordpress.com blog, this may be the only way. In wordpress.com you have a lot of good stuff, but some restriction too.

If you are using a self-installed version of wordpress, you can insert this code into your theme, in the file functions.php as [explained here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

You can also use a plugin for this, which is simpler. A good plugin for custom posts is [WCK](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/).